# Join 4 tables across 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

`TB1, TB2, TB3` are in one database on the server and `TB4` is on another database.

The column information needed for the join are as follows:

- TB1 - column a1, b2.
- TB2 - column a2, b2, c3.
- TB3 - column a3.
- TB4 - column a4.

`TB1, TB2, TB3` are related by `ID`
TB1's ID is the primary  key and the foreign keys in TB2, TB3 and TB4

I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Code:

select ID 
from TB1, TB2, TB3
where TB1.ID = TB2.TB1.ID

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: In my opinion, the question makes little sense and provides insufficient information.  Could you edit to show code tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "redundant information"? What is the relationship with TB4? "ID" must be a foreign key on some of these tables...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link them like this (don't forget to put the relation that you missed to say):

```
SELECT t1.a1, t1.b2, t2.a2, t2.b2, t2.c3, t3.a3, t4.a4
FROM db1..TB1 t1
INNER JOIN db1..TB2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN db1..TB3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID
INNER JOIN db2..TB4 t4 ON --put relation here
```

Also replace `db1` and `db2` by the database names on which each table is present.

---

One final note, your code it's giving redundant information because you didn't make all the restrictions. So, a cartesian product is produced.